# change default browser and filetype with powershell script

Tags: powershell

I tried this code but windows opens. How do I hide opened windows and run them in the background?

```
function Set-DefaultBrowser {

Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Windows.Forms'

Start-Process $env:windir\\system32\\control.exe -LoadUserProfile -Wait -ArgumentList '/name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=Firefox-308046B0AF4A39CB'

Sleep 5

[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{TAB 5}{ENTER}{TAB}{ENTER} ")

}

Set-DefaultBrowser;
```

Comment: is there a reason you're escaping `\[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys\]`? Also, set the filetype of what? I found this [site](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/script-to-set-default-browser-on-windows/) that shows you how to set the default browser using WMI, but it requires a restart. The solution you've provided relies on the GUI interaction so you're best bet is to use the linked site above, or using some xml way that I cam across googling as well. As for setting the filetype, you can use this [module](https://github.com/DanysysTeam/PS-SFTA).

Comment: WMI codes didn't work for me and this was incorrectly received + ...      $obj = New-CimInstance -Namespace $namespaceName -ClassName $cla ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (MDM_Policy_Conf...ationDefaults02:CimInstance) [New-CimInstance], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 7,Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimCmdlets.NewCimInstanceCommand